# Data on age demographics by individual age for some uniformly distributed measure

Tags: usa, demographics

**tl;dr:** I'm looking for data on age demographics in the US for *individual ages* on some characteristic/measure that is reasonably "smooth" across the population. In other words, no sharp distinction like "number who drink" where we'll see a huge change at the drinking age, or "number of unemployed" where we'll see a huge change at ~60yrs.

Ideally something within the past 10yrs and for an even year (aligns with election data I already have).

That said, I'll take what I can get, and data on individual ages has been hard to find, period.

This is my first post here, so if context is appreciate on this site, see below. Otherwise, this is the short and sweet request!

---

I recently read [a theory](https://www.depernolaw.com/uploads/2/7/0/2/27029178/collective_response_to_motions_for_protective_order_040921.pdf) on voter fraud with the core finding being that one could predict votes cast from registered voters, claiming that the resemblance between the shapes of the two curves is too similar to be accidental.

I believe this is an age-based analog of this [xkcd cartoon](https://xkcd.com/1138/), and that the "illusion" (i.e. this "wow" factor on shape alignment between two curves) stems from the fact that we never see data for individual age demographics plotted.

I did find it for all elections going back to 2000 to show that VAP, VEP, registrations, and all curves always match in shape. No surprises, as of those who exist some smooth % multiplier across the ages tracks with those who register and vote (from that same population).

[image]

Now I'd like to find some preposterous dataset on individual age, showing that you can correlate *any* data along age demographics with any other data on age demographics because both track to the parent population (kind of like "any activity tends to happen more in summer, which is why burlaries and ice cream eating both go up").

That said, it needs to be something that is relatively "smooth" across each age. No sharp changes for e.g. drinking age or retirement. Perhaps the number of people by age who: visit the doctor, drive, travel out of state/country, get a passport, buy stock, watch youtube... anything like that where given some age being higher than average compared to neighboring ages, this disproportionate spike will carry through in the measure as well.

Comment: most survey datasets have linear age (see asdfree.com) but the census bureau also releases certain summaries broken down by linear age, like https://www.census.gov/newsroom/press-kits/2020/population-estimates-detailed.html

Comment: @AnthonyDamico I looked at one for age at the Census link and see 5yr groups. Are you able to cite a specific example from asdfree or the Census?

Comment: Annual Estimates of the Civilian Population by Single Year of Age and Sex for the United States and States: April 1, 2010 to July 1, 2019

Comment: @AnthonyDamico Thank you. My quest is for "data on age demographics in the US for individual ages *on some characteristic/measure*." I admit this is probably not clear enough... but I need something "about the population," not simply "the population." Does that make sense? Something about, that happens, that is done by the population. I want to show that measures derived from the population will, of course, correlate to the population.

Comment: @AnthonyDamico and, thank you again for that link. I'd seen a population pyramid on Wikipedia and for the life of me could not find the source. This is fantastic.